# id field which is not primary key in django django model

Tags: django, postgresql

Is it possible to create an **id field** in a model that is not primary_key in django? If so, how to do it? To be clearer, here is my model:

```
class GWS(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=20,primary_key=False)
    ...
```

What can I do to prevent the id field from being primary key?

```
api.GWS: (models.E004) 'id' can only be used as a field name if the field also sets 'primary_key=True'
```

Comment: **Yes**, but then you need another primary key.

Comment: I tried adding an Autofield field but django throws an error when applying the migrations

Comment: @leauradimin: exactly *what* error. If you already constructed the `GWS` model in a previous migration, this will likely not work, so you should create the table for that model with one migration.

Comment: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ERROR: several default values are specified for the "auto_field" column of the table

Comment: and how did you specify the `AutoField`? You can not set a default for the `AutoField`, it should thus be `otherfieldname = AutoField(primary_key=True)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to create an id field in a model that is not primary_key in django?

**Yes**, but then you need to specify another field that is the primary key, for example a [**`UUIDField`** field [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield):

```
from uuid import uuid4

class GWS(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    uuid = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid4)
    # …
```